# How to avoid weird topology with shrink-wrap when trying to retopologize really high mesh

Tags: mesh

I don't really know what i'm doing wrong in the whole process of sculpting and re-topology. 
is not like it's a horrible topology but is not smooth.

It is has to do withe the fact that the mesh is 5 million polys and shrink wrap is not precis with that many polys and i should do it the hard way just using snap to faces?

[image]

Comment: In fact YES ... shrinkwrap could be used when the amount of polys are nearly the same on both objects but You want to reduce polycount so plan to use MUCH LESS polys - use snapping. You could also use some retopo addon, but I dunno if there is a free one. Maybe use BSurfaces addon (its already a part of Blender)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was as the i suspect, the topology was tooo high and messy
I find a good way to solve this problems, just decimate the mesh and then use this videos to get a better topology in just minutes for the shrink-wrap 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBiR262Wdfc&ab_channel=GrantAbbitt